# Realm Cloud and SyncCredentials iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So I have been playing with the Swift iOS Quickstart example which works fine as it is in the tutorial. It uses the following for credentials:

```
let creds = SyncCredentials.nickname(textField.text!, isAdmin: true)
```

I made sure that Username / Password was enabled in Setting on my Realm Cloud instance, created an alert view to accommodate username and password fields (btw the generated email when signing up works as advertised), and then attempted to create a different Realm with a slightly different folder name.  I used the following for credentials:

```
let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: textField.text!, password: textField2.text!)
```

Although it authenticates me, it does not connect me to the new realm.  I went back and tried my new realm with just the nickname as in the example as above and it works fine.

Below is the log error message I am getting:

> {"type":"https://realm.io/docs/object-server/problems/access-denied","title":"The
>   path is invalid or current user has no
>   access.","status":403,"code":614}

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't find anything in the documentation for this yet.

Thanks!

Comment: This is error message `The path is invalid or current user has no access`
show if you are login with nickname `SyncCredentials.nickname` ??

Comment: It works fine as long as you use a nickname with no errors logged.  Only when you try to set it up to use username and password does it not work.  Rather it will set you up as a user but not connect you to any realms like the nickname login does.

Comment: try to use default username  try this `let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "realm-admin", password: "")`

Comment: Sorry just circling back to this.  It appears the only way this works is if the user is an administrator.  If they are not then it fails.